# Java - What does it means when a class is created with '<>'?

Tags: java, class

I just created a class like this: `NameOfTheClass<Raeaeraear>`. What does it means? And why can I put whatever random stuff I want?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: @JonSkeet can I email you a question ? :P

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was just kidding about [*this*](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/08/22/stack-overflow-and-personal-emails.aspx)

Comment: this is off-topic but "grumpy curmudgeon or (worse) like an egocentric pseudo-celebrity" :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called Generics. Generics is used to "tell" a instance of an class what kind of type it is going to work with, take f.ex a List

```
List<People> myPeopleList = new ArrayList<People>();
```

Here the list is parameterized. If you take a look at the List-interface source code, it is declared like this which means  the interface List is generic.

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
...
```

In your case the class NameOfTheClass would be implementet somewhat like this, Note: Generics can be applied to both a Class or an Interface.

```
public class NameOfTheClass<E> {
....
public doSome(E e){
    doSomeGenericOperationWith(e);
}
```

This class could be used like this:

```
NameOfTheClass<AType> instance = new NameOfTheClass<AType>();
Atype yourType = ...
doSome(yourType);
```

Note: Any use of the doSome()-method will require a parameter of type Atype, this will be handled by the Java-compiler. So if you try to call the method with some other type, an compile-error will rise.

More readings : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `<>` the compiler turns off checking the generic type.  When the compiler needs to know the type you can't use the `<>`

e.g.

```
// compiles ok because the compiler knows not to check the type.
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(); 

// compiler needs to know the type, so this doesn't compile.
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>() {};
```

Comment: Something missing here? I cant se how any of this two lines will compile.

Comment: @ThomasJohanEggum, what is the problem with the first one?

Comment: My bad, used compiler compliance level 6. This is a new Java-7 feature.  
http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/09/java7-features.html